# How to fillter and view only a substring of ip table Logs with tailf and sed?

Tags: sed, iptables, tail

one line of iptable log is:

```
Jan  1 21:41:19 x kernel: [838760.885218] IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:00:x:00:00:x:00:x:x:x:x SRC=x.x.x.x DST=x.x.x.x LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=37739 DPT=53 LEN=50
```

and to watch it live , i used :

```
tailf /var/log/kern.log
```

but as you can see, it contains a lot of information in it. so i tried to view only source and destination field of that line.

I changed my command to some thing like this :

```
tailf /var/log/kern.log | sed -n -e 's/^.*DST: //p'
```

but still nothing, Is there any way i can change it to show me only source and destination IP addresses? or should i go to more complicated solution than a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] tried to view only source and destination field of that line.

I would use `grep`. Something like this:

```
echo "Jan  1 21:41:19 x kernel: [838760.885218] IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:00:x:00:00:x:00:x:x:x:x SRC=192.168.1.10 DST=192.168.1.20 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=37739 DPT=53 LEN=50" | egrep -o 'SRC=[0-9.]* DST=[0-9.]*'
SRC=192.168.1.10 DST=192.168.1.20
```

In your case it would become:

```
tailf /var/log/kern.log | egrep -o 'SRC=[0-9.]* DST=[0-9.]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the maximum column exsists from below command

`awk '{print NF}' /var/log/kern.log/sort -rn | head -1` and assigned that value in for loop maximum value

From given input maximum column exsists is 22 so we assigned the value in 22 in for loop

```
for ((i=1;i<=22;i++)); do tail -f /var/log/kern.log |awk -v i="$i" '$i ~ "SRC" {print $i}';tail -f /var/log/kern.log | awk -v i="$i" '$i ~ "DST" {print $i}'  ; done

output
SRC=x.x.x.x
DST=x.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect? The line doesn't contain `DST:`. Use

```
sed -n 's/.*\(SRC=.*DST=[^ ]\).*/\1/p'
```

to remove everything part the match inside the `\(\)`